# What is the Routing AuthGuard lifetime of Angular 2 routes?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I've implemented AuthGuards (CanActivate) to my routes using observable subscriptions to check weather logged-in user have right to open some components or not.

I guess guards live for the lifetime of application so I don't feel I should unsubscribe on destroy, how ever I might be wrong.

What is the situation with guards? Do I need to unsubscribe my subscriptions or they live same with app?

Comment: What do you subscribe to?

Comment: a BehaviorSubject in my auth service that gets nexted when firebase.auth receives uid (after successful login)

Comment: Please add the code to your question.

Comment: I can add the code, but in reality what I want to know is what is the lifespan of route guards. Are they destroyed after some time route visited or they live long with main app itself...regardless I use Firebase or not.